# How to extract the context of an XML element with lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I want to extract the citation context of PubMed Central papers, given the following data structure ([Journal Article Tag Suite, JATS](https://jats.nlm.nih.gov/)):

```
<p>
This is a sentence. 
This is a citing sentence [<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR1">1</xref>]. 
This is another sentence
</p>
```

A real example file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u4g1sisil33wnhu/PMC1914234.xml?dl=0

I want to extract "This is a citing sentence" as the context of reference with rid `CR1`, and do not extract the previous and the following sentences.

I am able to locate the paragraph that contains the `xref` tag, but I don't know how to extract the correct sentence only. The XPath command `string()` or `text()` of this paragraph only return texts without structural information (e.g. tag) so I have difficulties in locating the exact sentence.

Is there a solution to solve this problem?

EDIT: I think I need an XPath command that can extract texts with structural information, instead of using `string()` and `text()` on its parent element.

Comment: can you show the xml structure and also what you have tried so far?

Comment: @WeavingBird1917 Thank you! Are you suggesting I should not parse it with lxml but read the raw XML and do the extraction with regex instead? As I mentioned above, I can't get structural information using the `string()` or `text()` XPath command. If I parse it with lxml, then I can't use regex?

Comment: There is no concept of "sentences" in XML. There only is text. You can extract the text, with lxml, but after that you still need to define what a sentence is -  without any ambiguity such as *"it ends with `.`"* (many things contain a `.`) - in order to split it correctly using Python.

Comment: @johnashu I've added a link to a real file. I can locate the paragraph that contains the `xref` element I want, but I have difficulties in extracting the exact sentence.

Comment: @Tomalak I have difficulties in extracting the text and also keeping the structural information. Both `string()` and `text()` eliminate tags and return only pure texts, so I can not locate the position of  `xref` element.

Comment: can u give an example of ur ouptut

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ref id  `<ref id="some ID">`,

You can leverage Beautiful Soup to easily find the data based on the ref id.

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


fName = 'PMC1914234.xml'
rid = 'CR1'

pattern = r'.*?\](.*)[\,\.\]\ ].*'
"""
        .*? # matches any character but a newline. * is a meta-character and means Repeat this 0 or more times. ? makes the * non-greedy, i.e., . will match up as few chars as possible before hitting a '['.
        \] # escaped character  ] = \]
        (.*) #Parenthesis 'groups' whatever is inside it and you can later retrieve the groups by their numeric IDs or names (if they're given one).
        \[.* # ens char  (escaped) change this if required to another char)
        """

with open(fName) as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "xml")

#find paragraphs (<p>)
paragraphs = soup.find_all('p') # find a ll paragraphs

# loop through each one
for text in paragraphs:
    # look for the rid specified.
    found = text.find(rid=rid)
    if found:
        print(text.text)
        # match the item between the tags.. If there is no other [ to hit, you might need to add something else to the list.            
        match = match = re.search(pattern, text.text).group(1)
        print(match) # there maybe more groups, you can iterate like below
# >>> However, when these pathways are deranged because of genetic mutations of enzymes involved or relative deficiencies of folate, vitamin B6 or vitamin B12, the serum concentration of Hcy increases.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am trying to extract the texts from the paragraph where the references are cited rather than from the reference section.